# Errors with create-react-app my-app redux with new react 18.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, npx

I am trying to create a react app with redux with the general command of npx and I am getting this error

**command**

```
npx create-react-app myp --template redux
```

**error**

```
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3 || ^17" from react-redux@7.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!   react-redux@"^7.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\rickb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rickb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-30T18_49_41_783Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @reduxjs/toolkit@^1.5.1 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2 react-redux@^7.2.3` failed
```

What should I do to remove this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new error, and realistically your only solution is to just add react-redux with Yarn.

`yarn add react-redux`

Note: I suggest downgrading your React to version 17 for the time being, Since React v18 is not supporting Redux Toolkit and other Libraries. On my end I am using Redux saga and it is having issues with v18.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how can I downgrade to react 17. What is the command ?

Comment: Just go into your package.json and change the react version to 17.0.2

Answer (score 2):

`npx create-react-app redux-ts --template redux-typescript` wasn't working for me yesterday but it's working today, give your original command a try again.

Comment: Yes this has been fixed. You might want to update to the React-Redux  8 beta after installing though - that doesn't happen automatically yet.

Comment: Yes I just checked now and it has started working now